# SSRS Chart Axis

Tags: reporting-services, charts, axis

I am self-teaching myself SSRS, but I can't figure out this issue. I am doing a bar chart that shows the number of cases by time group, the different time groups are on the x-axis and include "12AM-2AM", "2AM-4AM", etc. However depending on the day I choose (in the parameter), their is not a case for every time group and so SSRS is only showing those time groups with a case,  but I would like it to show every time group from 12AM to llPM and just show 0 when their is no case for that time group. Any tips for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to alter the properties on the chart. There should be a custom attributes section. Set the 'EmptyPointValue' to 'zero' which should give you the chart that you are looking for.